# TTT-Server: Connection failed after 6 retries

Tags: linux, docker-compose, server, steam, garrys-mod

I would like to run a TTT (Trouble in Terrorist Town) server on my own server. I would like to implement this with a Docker container. The server is displayed to me, but there is no password query or anything else. Because after a while it always says "Connection failed after

**Creating Docker Container with docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.8' 

services:
  ttt: 
    container_name: ttt-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      # Port 27016 because my ARK-Server use 27015
      - "27016:27015/tcp"
      - "27016:27015/udp"
      - "27005:27005/tcp"
      - "27005:27005/udp"

    volumes:
      - tttserver:/home/steam 
    command: tail -f /dev/null

volumes: 
  tttserver:
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && \
    apt-get install -y \
        software-properties-common \
        wget \
        curl \
    && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    nano 

RUN echo "root:<password>" | chpasswd

RUN sudo useradd -m steam 

RUN sudo usermod -aG sudo steam

RUN echo "steam:<steampassword>" | chpasswd

RUN sudo -u steam -H -s

RUN sudo add-apt-repository multiverse; sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386; sudo apt update -y

RUN echo steam steam/question select "I AGREE" | sudo debconf-set-selections
RUN echo steam steam/license note '' | sudo debconf-set-selections

RUN sudo apt install steamcmd -y

RUN sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates -y

RUN /usr/games/steamcmd \
    +login anonymous \
    +force_install_dir /home/steam/tttserver \
    +app_update 4020 validate \
    +quit

RUN echo 'gamemode terrortown' > /home/steam/tttserver/garrysmod/cfg/autoexec.cfg

RUN echo '#!/bin/bash' > /home/steam/tttserver/startServer.sh
RUN echo './srcds_run -console -maxplayers 16 -game garrysmod +gamemode terrortown +map gm_construct' >> /home/steam/tttserver/startServer.sh

WORKDIR /home/steam/tttserver

RUN chmod +x startServer.sh

COPY ./server.cfg /home/steam/tttserver/garrysmod/cfg/server.cfg

WORKDIR /home/steam/tttserver

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

**The "server.cfg"**

```
hostname "<severname>"
rcon_password "<rcon-password>"
sv_password "<serverpassword>"

//DNA
ttt_killer_dna_range 300
ttt_killer_dna_basetime 100


//Prep
ttt_firstpreptime 45
ttt_preptime_seconds 30
ttt_posttime_seconds 10


//Round length
ttt_haste 0
// ttt_haste_starting_minutes 5
// ttt_haste_minutes_per_death 0.5

ttt_roundtime_minutes 10



//Map Switching
ttt_round_limit 4
ttt_time_limit_minutes 75

//ttt_always_use_mapcycle 0


//Player Counts
ttt_minimum_players 2
ttt_traitor_pct 0.33
ttt_traitor_max 32
ttt_detective_pct 0.13
ttt_detective_max 32
ttt_detective_min_players 5
ttt_detective_karma_min 600


//Karma
ttt_karma 1
ttt_karma_strict 1
ttt_karma_starting 1000
ttt_karma_max 1000
ttt_karma_ratio 0.001
ttt_karma_kill_penalty 15
ttt_karma_round_increment 5
ttt_karma_clean_bonus 30
ttt_karma_traitordmg_ratio 0.0003
ttt_karma_traitorkill_bonus 40
ttt_karma_low_autokick 1
ttt_karma_low_amount 300
ttt_karma_low_ban 0
ttt_karma_low_ban_minutes 60
ttt_karma_persist 1
ttt_karma_clean_half 0.25

//Other
ttt_postround_dm 1
ttt_no_nade_throw_during_prep 0
ttt_weapon_carrying 1
ttt_weapon_carrying_range 50
ttt_teleport_telefrags 1
ttt_ragdoll_pinning 1
ttt_ragdoll_pinning_innocents 1
ttt_use_weapon_spawn_scripts 1
ttt_spawn_wave_interval 2

// server logging
log on
sv_logbans 1
sv_logecho 1
sv_logfile 1
sv_log_onefile 0

// operation
sv_lan 0
sv_region 255

exec banned_user.cfg
exec banned_ip.cfg
```

.....................................................................
These are all the settings and configurations that I have done so far

After building the container, I start the server by running the “startServer.sh” script

**Logs**

```
************** WARNING ***************
Running the dedicated server as root
is highly discouraged. It is generally
unnecessary to use root privileges to
execute the dedicated server.
**************************************


Auto detecting CPUntinue to launch in 1 secondss
Using default binary: ./srcds_linux
Server will auto-restart if there is a crash.

WARNING: Failed to load 32-bit libtinfo.so.5 or libncurses.so.5.
  Please install (lib32tinfo5 / ncurses-libs.i686 / equivalent) to enable readline.

Couldn't load shader dll: game_shader_generic_garrysmod_srv.soConVarRef mat_dxlevel doesn't point to an existing                                                                                                                              ConVar
Game_srv.so loaded for "Garry's Mod"
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 4000
Initializing Steam libraries for Workshop..
[S_API] SteamAPI_Init(): Loaded local 'steamclient.so' OK.
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 3 milliseconds to initialize
dlmopen steamservice.so failed: steamservice.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
SteamInternal_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  ##Censored## [API loaded no]
[S_API FAIL] Tried to access Steam interface SteamUser023 before SteamAPI_Init succeeded.
WS: No +host_workshop_collection or it is invalid!
Unknown command "cl_cmdrate"
Unknown command "cl_updaterate"
Unknown command "rate"
Changing gamemode to Trouble in Terrorist Town (terrortown)
Network: IP ##Censored##, mode MP, dedicated Yes, ports 27015 SV / 27005 CL
Error loading cfg/trusted_keys_base.txt
Error loading cfg/pure_server_minimal.txt
PREP OK
Included TTT language file: brazilian_portuguese.lua
Included TTT language file: chef.lua
Included TTT language file: english.lua
Included TTT language file: french.lua
Included TTT language file: german.lua
Included TTT language file: italian.lua
Included TTT language file: japanese.lua
Included TTT language file: russian.lua
Included TTT language file: simpchinese.lua
Included TTT language file: spanish.lua
Included TTT language file: swedish.lua
Included TTT language file: tradchinese.lua
Included TTT language file: ukrainian.lua
Trouble In Terrorist Town gamemode initializing...
ConVarRef room_type doesn't point to an existing ConVar
Executing dedicated server config file server.cfg
Using map cycle file cfg/mapcycle.txt.
Initializing Steam libraries for secure Internet server
[S_API] SteamAPI_Init(): Loaded local 'steamclient.so' OK.
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 2 milliseconds to initialize
dlmopen steamservice.so failed: steamservice.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
SteamInternal_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  ##Censored## [API loaded no]
No account token specified; logging into anonymous game server account.  (Use sv_setsteamaccount to login to a p                                                                                                                             ersistent account.)
Server ranking in server browser will be negatively impacted due to sv_setsteamaccount not being set.
Server logging enabled.
Server logging data to file logs/L0229001.log
L 02/29/2024 - 15:01:19: Log file started (file "logs/L0229001.log") (game "garrysmod") (version "9040")
'banned_user.cfg' not present; not executing.
'banned_ip.cfg' not present; not executing.
Connection to Steam servers successful.
   Public IP is ##Censored##.
Assigned anonymous gameserver Steam ID [A-1:##Censored##].
VAC secure mode is activated.
```

**Garrys Mod**
[image: In Game]